# Zikula CSRF token is invalid

Tags: forms, symfony, zikula

I'm modifying the template edit.html.twig in order to hide any fields.
I have modified the editAction in my controller for load my template too.
I'm having a problem with the CSRF. The token CSRF is not valid, when I submit the form. I have tried to reload the form, but I have the same result. (The module was created in MOST 1.1.0 and ZK 2.0.2, and I'm modifying the edit.html.twig)

What's the problem?

I have tried insert the fields that I erased, but the problem persist.

Message Error: "The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form."
    _token (
    "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType"
    )

I have detected that the token is not created in the template. If i have this code, the token is generated.
    {{ form_end(form) }}
If i change the code to:
    {{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
The token is not generated.

So, i have add
    {{ form_widget(form._token) }}
Now the token is generated, but when i submit the form, i have the same message "The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form."

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot help you with out more information. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide the specific code and error messages you are getting

Comment: I have update the post with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

again and do the following in order to remove the unwanted fields.

Edit `modules/YourVendor/YourAppModule/Form/Type/YourFormType.php` and add something like:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

...

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    $builder->remove('yourUnwantedField');
}
```

Finally add the path to file which has been amended to the `skipFiles` property of your model's settings container:

```
skipFiles "
    Form/Type/YourFormType.php
"
```

This ensures the generator won't re-create and override this file, so your custom code is kept also after regenerations.

Comment: Correct, but i have the same message with the token. I have edit my post.

Comment: I don't just want hide fields in the template. I have think change more details, so that the answer is not valid for my purpose.. Thanks.